# Cannot identify this sans-serif font from business card

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif

[image]

This is from a business card I wanted to digitize.

I have trouble identifying this font. Its properties are quite generic, so Identifont was not really useful. WhatTheFont also did not give any close results.

Comment: I know you say those websites didn't give you the correct results but perhaps you adjust your method. For example, searching specifically by a letter or two. In this case perhaps the letter "A" and "G", then go from there?

Answer (score 1):

After searching for the business in the sample, I discovered that it's located in Clausthal, Germany. From here we can presumably narrow this down to a German typeface, more precisely of the Rotunda variety, to find a close match. The `E`, `A`, and `G` are most noticeably not an exact match, but you may be able to modify it as a vector shape in illustrator to fit the sample more closely:

[image]

Source: [WhatFontIs.com](http://www.whatfontis.com/Wallau-Unzial-Bold.font?text=GROSSE%27SCHE%20BUCHHANDLUNG)